# Spritekit | Swift 3 | GameScene.sks - Physics properties only applied to one SKSpritenode

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I have a GameScene.sks where I have added two SkSpritenodes both called trampoline. The code gives the trampoline object a physics body etc. but when run. Only the first trampoline has a body.

Any idea why it does not get applied to all nodes with the same name?

```
//Trampoline
var trampoline: SKSpriteNode?       

 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
trampoline = childNode(withName: "trampoline") as? SKSpriteNode
            trampoline?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: (trampoline?.size)!)
            trampoline?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            trampoline?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            trampoline?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
            trampoline?.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
childNode(withName: "trampoline") as? SKSpriteNode
```

will only return a single node called `trampoline` which you then assign to your `trampoline` variable; you need to enumerate over ALL nodes called trampoline and set their physics bodies. E.g.

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("trampoline") { trampolineNode, _ in
    trampolineNode?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: (trampolineNode?.size)!)
    trampolineNode?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    trampolineNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    trampolineNode?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    trampolineNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
}
```

Watch out for that `.isDynamic` property; if 'false', the body won't be involved in collisions or contacts.

Comment: The trampolineNode is being treated as a SKNode. Thus TrampolineNode?.size for the physics body does not work. How can I declare trampolineNode to be a SKSpritenode?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Just had to ammend the Physics body statement to  trampoline.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: (trampoline.frame.size.width/2), height: (trampoline.frame.size.height/2))

Comment: @user3482617 Good. You could also cast it with 'let trampoline = trampolineNode as! SKSpriteNode', which is quite common as enumerateChildNode only returns SKNodes.